# How to query by ActiveRecord depending If the value of an attribute is empty or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a variable that could be set or left empty. In the first case the query looks fine, but in the second one I can't find how it works.

Checking If :

```
if params['customer_id'] == ""
  @customer_id = "";
else
  @customer_id = params['customer_id']
end
```

The query

```
User.where("customer_id = ?",  @customer_id)
```

The problem is that If `""` ,the query returns nothing. I could write it as

```
 if params['customer_id'] == ""
   User.all
 else
   User.where("customer_id = ?",  params['customer_id']) 
 end
```

but first this is not DRY and second my query will include 10 * where's so this is not a very smart way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will refactor your query as:

```
@users = User.all
@users = @users.where(customer_id: params['customer_id']) if params['customer_id'].present?
```

Example:

```
@users = User.all
# User Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL
@users.where(email: 'arup').count
# (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."email" = $1  [["email", "arup"]]
```

*update*

## with scope

```
scope :with_or_without_customer, ->(customer_id) do
  customer_id.present? ? where(customer_id: customer_id) : all
end
```

*Note:*

[`Model.all`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) now returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, rather than an array of records. Use `Relation#to_a` if you really want an array.

In some specific cases, this may cause breakage when upgrading. However in most cases the `ActiveRecord::Relation` will just act as a lazy-loaded array and there will be no problems.

Comment: Or make it a scope on the user model `scope :for_customer, ->(customer_id) { where(customer_id: customer_id) if customer_id.present }`

Comment: What If several other `.where` will be added?

Comment: @ChrisV. it will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which can be chained.  So adding further clauses is fine

Comment: @ChrisV. you need to think then, and separate those.

Comment: @j-dexx this sounds good. Can you please post it in a separate answer ? I haven't thought I could use scopes and it will keep my controller slim, moving the conditions to the model.

Comment: You should accept Arup's answer, all I did was convert what he'd put into a scope.

Comment: @ArupRakshit `where` is not worked on the `Array` and 2) it will fires queries two time's if `customer_id` present

Comment: You guys are awesome. One last question. Isn't more logical to move this to scopes and keep my controller away from fat ? :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit it gives error `undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007fe720a0bd60>` for `rails 3.2`

Comment: @VishalJAIN Myself is Rails 4.2. They probably then changed the lazy loading. :) Can you try it to higher version ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I did this - I am just asking to follow the "best practice"!

Comment: @ArupRakshit what about previous version? i think you need to replace it with `User.where(1)`

Comment: @ChrisV. check now with _scope_ .

Comment: @VishalJAIN current one is working good, and rails will be upgraded day by day. So up-to-date answer is fine. Can you please post yours which you are thinking to be better also. I just _wanted_ to show you that `.all` behaviour is changed, that is why I linked the _CHANGELOG_. But your `.all` comment will help future readers also, which is why I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
@condition = "1"
@condition = {:customer_id => params['customer_id']} if params['customer_id'].present?
```

You can create your condition first then fire the query on database so that it will fire query only single time on database:

```
@users = User.where(@condition)
```

Comment: Good thought. But my approach will not do also 2 query due to _lazy loading_ feature. That's the whole point. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit for some versions of rails it will not support your lazy loading so it will load complete dataset

Comment: Yes, but from Rails 4.0, it is guaranteed that it will do _lazy load_ . So in lower version of Rails 4, your one fits of-course good. +1